# JFreeChart plotting

Tags: java, graph, plot, jfreechart, axes

A question regarding the use of JFreeChart in Java. I want to plot a line graph based on two parameters. These parameters are the values of a two-dimensional array. Unfortunately, I am not being able to get some examples from the Internet working on my laptop. Can someone help to figure it out and show a working example or give tips on how to do it?

Comment: [1. JFreeChart Tutorial](http://dvillela.servehttp.com:4000/apostilas/jfreechart_tutorial.pdf) `AND` [2. JFreeChart - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JFreeChart/article.html)

Comment: More examples cited in the tag [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info).